# Sequencing of functions and passing the results along to the next function

Tags: javascript

I am working on practicing js concepts (not exam or job related). Below is an example implementation of one of the program and based on it I have to create the

> sequence

function.

```
var getUser = function(userId) {
  return function(cb) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      cb(null, {userId: userId, name: 'Joe'});
    }, Math.random() * 100);
  };
};

var upperCaseName = function(cb, user) {
  cb(null, user.name.toUpperCase());
};

var userThunk = getUser(22);

sequence([userThunk, upperCaseName])(function(err, data) {
  console.log(data); // JOE
});
```

What I have understood so far by looking at the code is that the array arguments are functions and they are executed in order and the return value from each function is somehow passed to the next function. 
What I fail to understand is how the return function of getUser with cb argument could be used with upperCaseName to produce the intended results.

Also, the concept related to the problem I am highlighting does it has any name ?

Comment: What is `async.sequence` ?? You mean `async function sequence()` ?

Comment: at the end of code snippet you would find async.sequence

Comment: That's exactly what I'm asking. What is `sequence`? a property of `async`?

Comment: sorry, misunderstood you. async is the name of my js file

Comment: I will edit the question and remove the async from the code snippet to avoid further confussion

Comment: Can you share the sequence's code?

Comment: I see similar code here: https://github.com/kolodny/exercises/blob/master/async/README.md 

You seem to be missing some of it.

Comment: @mtmoran Yes, I didnt mention the test code as it would make the post longer.

Comment: @Ele that is what I have to write :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `async.sequence` does as that code was not provided.

To answer your questions, you are dealing with few concepts.

## The first one is **Callbacks**

A callback function is a function passed into another function as an argument, which is then invoked inside the outer function to complete some kind of routine or action.

Taken from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function)

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BMUiFMZr7vk&vl=en) might help in explaining.

## The second one is **Currying**

Currying is a technique where you can pass all of the arguments a function is expecting and get the result, or pass a subset of those arguments and get a function back that’s waiting for the rest of the arguments.

Check out [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/currying-in-functional-javascript/) tutorial for a more detailed explanation.

## The third thing you are dealing with is **Asynchronous programming**

JavaScript is asynchronous meaning it permits other processing to continue before the a potential previous task has completed.

Here is a good [tutorial](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/front-end-javascript/introduction-to-asynchronous-javascript).